# SQlachemy setup models of tables that are on different databases

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I have two table (ta, tb) that ta is on database DA and tb is on database DB .

If I would use raw sql I would like to do a query like:

```
SELECT `da`.`ta`.x, `db`.`tb`.y FROM `da`.`ta`.x, `db`.`tb`.y 
WHERE `da`.`ta`.id = `db`.`tb`.ta_id
```

This works as expected when I run it.

I would like to be able to setup 2 models for the above tables using declarative Base.

```
class TA(Base):
    __tablename__ = ??????

    id = Column ....
    x = Column ...

class TB(Base):
    __tablename__ = ????

    id = Column ....
    y = Column ....
    ta_id = Column with Foreign key on ta.id
```

What should I put to the tablename ?
I tried to put 'da.ta' and 'db.tb and it does not work.

I would like to mention that my engine connects to the DA database.